# Python: Circular dependency of dataclasses / Forward variable declaration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, forward-declaration, circular-reference, python-dataclasses

So, I have these two dataclasses in a file:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    children: List[B]

@dataclass
class B:
    parent: A
```

, which are possible with the use of the `__future__.annotations` feature.

Then I have two other files, each with a bunch of objects for each type that are static for my project.

File `objects_A`:

```
import objects_B

obj_a1 = A(
    children=[
        objects_B.obj_b1,
        objects_B.obj_b2
    ]
)
```

File `objects_B`:

```
import objects_A

obj_b1 = B(
    parent=objects_A.obj_a1
)

obj_b2 = B(
    parent=objects_A.obj_a1
)
```

Obviously, there a circular dependency problem between the files, but it wouldn't work even if they were in the same file, as a variable of one type depends on the other to succeed.
Initialising the `B` objects inside `obj_a1` also won't work as there is no concept of `self` here.

At the moment, I'm setting `parent` to `None` (against the type hinting), and then do a loop on `obj_a1` to set them up:

```
for obj_b in obj_a1.children:
    obj_b.parent = obj_a1
```

Any bright ideas folks?
Don't know if it helps, but these objects are static (they will not change after these declarations) and they have kind of a parent-children relationship (as you surely have noticed).
If possible, I would like to have the variables of each type in different files.

Comment: you are mapping 1 object to another in essence, why can't you make some sort of dictionary? e.g: `dict = {PARENT_OBJ: [CHILDREN]}`

Comment: The idea is to pass an object of type `B` around the project and be able to access other stuff from parent `A` without needing to use other structures, like dictionaries.

Comment: There is no way to have actual object references that have circular dependencies. You either have indirect references through a mapping that will be realized eventually, as Peter S proposed, or  you initialize all `A`s with an empty list for children, and only add the `B`s to the relationship when their object file is executed. Do none of these two options work?

Answer (score 4):

I know that I'm late but I'll just leave my answer here for others to use.

According to [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), python 3.7 has introduced lazy evaluation of annotations which can be very useful in the case of a circular dependency.

```py
@dataclass
class StudentData:
    school: 'SchoolData'

@dataclass
class SchoolData:
    students: StudentData
```

As you can see, the `SchoolData` type annotation is wrapped inside quotations which allows you to reference the `SchoolData` type before its declaration.

Comment: would you please mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use a base class as an alternative to forward declaration.

```
@dataclass
class ParentBase:
    children: List[object]


@dataclass
class Child:
    parent: ParentBase


@dataclass
class Parent(ParentBase):
    children: List[Child]



parent = Parent(children=[])
child = Child(parent=parent)
parent.children.append(child)
```

This will work. I have added the `children: List[object]` in the `ParentBase`. This is not necessary for this code to work, but if you add it your IDE can help you when you start accessing `child.parent.`.

This will **not** stop anyone from just instantiating a `Child` with a `ParentBase`. To solve that problem, you could do something like this:

```
@dataclass
class ParentBase(abc.ABC):
    children: List[object]

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __post_init__(self):
        pass


@dataclass
class Child:
    parent: ParentBase


@dataclass
class Parent(ParentBase):
    children: List[Child]

    def __post_init__(self):
        pass


parent = Parent(children=[])
child = Child(parent=ParentBase())  # TypeError
child = Child(parent=parent)
parent.children.append(child)
```

It might be too defensive and too much boilerplate code. It depends on the preference of your team whether you want to make this safer.